# How to hide a div using an ASP.NET Checkbox?

Tags: asp.net, html, checkbox, hide

i'm trying to do this assigning an method to the event on the checkbox tag like this:

```
    OnCheckedChanged="ShowDiv"
```

However, i'm not succesfull at all. How to do it? Here's my method:

```
    public void ShowDiv(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        var div = FindControl("ListaEmOutrosDocumentos") as HtmlGenericControl;
        var checkbox = FindControl("Principal") as CheckBox;

        if(checkbox.Checked == true)
        {
            div.Style.Clear();
            div.Style.Add("display","block");
        }
        else
        {
            div.Style.Clear();
            div.Style.Add("display","none");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the checkbox nested inside something else?

Comment: Does the `display` style attribute get rendered when the page re-renders?  What value does it have?

Comment: Also, I assume that you are posting back after checking the checkbox, either by setting AutoPostBack or having a separate postback trigger, such as a button.  Is this so?

Comment: @IrishChieftain The checkbox is inside a div.

Comment: @AnnL. I didn't think about de AutoPostBack setting. I'll try that!

Comment: Could you please post the complete HTML? Need to see the structure of your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way using server side code only

Aspx

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" style="height:200px;width:100px;background-color:Blue"></div>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowHideDiv" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    oncheckedchanged="chkShowHideDiv_CheckedChanged" Text="Hide Div"  />
```

Code behind

```
 protected void chkShowHideDiv_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myDiv.Visible = chkShowHideDiv.Checked ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using an ASP.NET `Panel` control instead of a `div`.  That will have a Visible property that you can set.

Comment: It may introduce possible side effects. When the Visible property is set to false, the control is not rendered at all. display=none does a bit different thing: the control is rendered, but the visibility is controlled by CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it worked.

```
<div id="ListaEmOutrosDocumentos" runat="server">
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Principal" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="ShowDiv"/>
        </div>
```

Code Behind

```
public void ShowDiv(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var div = ListaEmOutrosDocumentos as HtmlGenericControl;
        var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

        if (checkbox.Checked == true)
        {
            div.Style.Clear();
            div.Style.Add("display", "block");
        }
        else
        {
            div.Style.Clear();
            div.Style.Add("display", "none");
        }
    }
```